# Identifying a determinantal condition

Tags: real-analysis, determinants

Has the following condition already been studied and, if so, is there a known class of functions that satisfy it?

> **Condition.** For a fixed $n > 0$, all the $2 \times 2$ minors of the matrix
>   $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & x & \dotsm & x^n \\\
> 1 & f & \dotsm & f^n
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$, where $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $f \neq 0,x$.

In other words, I would like to characterise the functions $f$ for which $x^if^j - x^jf^i$, with $0 \leq i < j \leq n$, are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$.

**Addendum:** If it simplifies the analysis, $f$ can be assumed analytic. Even a result when $f$ is a polynomial of degree bounded by $d$ would be useful.